# Python PDF how to add bookmark url instead of page number

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using python 3.6 and PyPDF2 to create bookmarks in a pdf.
Instead of adding a bookmark to a page within the pdf. I want to add a url (eg. https://stackoverflow.com) as a bookmark.

Something like this?

```
output.addBookmark('TEST', 'https://stackoverflow.com', parent=None)
```

I don't think PyPDF2 supports something like this or does it? Is there another library that can support this?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

output = PdfFileWriter()
input = PdfFileReader(open('test.pdf', 'rb'))
output.addPage(input.getPage(0))
output.addBookmark('TEST', 0, parent=None)  # add bookmark
outputStream = open('output.pdf', 'wb')
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: @KJ The code I posted works fine but I don't want to link to a section in the pdf. I want it to link to a web page.

Comment: @KJ I thought it would be something easy to do because it's easy but tedious to do manually. The bookmarks in my sample pdf link to web pages, if you want to see the results I'm trying to get. Sample pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ld-CwHfA2VpWeqCGl8Id0K8opsNTi51V/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late but hear me out. I had to solve the same problem and since there is literally 0 information on this anywhere, I've investigated the issue and have managed to find the answer. It's not my most efficient/nicest code but definitely one of my proudest since nobody before did this.

The problem one faces is that there is no Pdf library for python that solves all
pdf related problems. Each tackle problems differently and some can do stuff that others can't. For this purpose, I had to use 2 libraries for the two functions below. `PyPDF2` is here to add the bookmarks to the pdf. `Pdfrw` is here to alter those bookmarks to have the action of opening a url.

In short, we create a new pdf with the added bookmarks, and another new one with the changed bookmarks actions that point to a url.

One thing to mention is that for some reason (for me at least) `PyPDF2` adds all bookmarks in a way that if you have multiple ones, they all become child elements to the previous bookmark. this is why we have the while loop, we collect all the bookmarks into a list with it, and then we can select the one we want.

If you already have bookmars and don't add them with `PyPDF2`, it might be enough to just loop over the `metaObjects` dictionary and get the values which contain the `/Title` key. Thus making the code significantly smaller. I've added this part as a comment.

Here an example on how to use the code below:

```
inputPdf = r"C:\......\first.pdf"
bookmarkedPdf = r"C:\......\second.pdf"
pdfWithWeblink = r"C:\......\final.pdf"

bookmarks = [
    {"Title": "The Phantom Menace", "Page": 5}, 
    {"Title": "Attack of the Clones", "Page": 10},
    {"Title": "Revenge Of The Sith", "Page": 13},
    {"Title": "A New hope", "Page": 18},
    {"Title": "The Empire Strikes Back", "Page": 26},
    {"Title": "Return of the Jedi", "Page": 32}
]

AddBookmarks(inputPdf, bookmarkedPdf, bookmarks)
AddWebLinkToBookmark(bookmarkedPdf, pdfWithWeblink, "Revenge Of The Sith", "https://stackoverflow.com")
```

The code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import pdfrw

def AddBookmarks(inputPdfPath: str, outputPdfPath: str, headers: dict) -> None:
    """ Adds bookmarks to a PDF. """

    output = PdfFileWriter()
    input = PdfFileReader(open(inputPdfPath, 'rb'))

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input.getPage(i))
        for header in headers:
            if header["Page"] - 1 == i:
                output.addBookmark(header["Title"], header["Page"] - 1, parent=None) 
                output.setPageMode("/UseOutlines")

    outputStream = open(outputPdfPath,'wb')
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()

    return outputPdfPath

def AddWebLinkToBookmark(inputPdfPath: str, outputPdfPath: str, bookmarkTitle: str, url: str) -> None:
    """ Changes the bookmark action to opening a web url. """

    # Reading the Pdf with pdfrw and collecting its meta objects. The bookmarks are among these.
    pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(inputPdfPath, decompress=True)
    metaObjects = pdf.indirect_objects

    # If you did not add the bookmarks with PyPDF2 previously, use this part for getting the bookmarkToChange variable:
    # bookmarkToChange = None
    # for _, annotation in metaObjects.items():
    #     if '/Title' in annotation:
    #         if annotation["/Title"] == f"({bookmarkTitle})".replace(" ", "\\040"):
    #             bookmarkToChange = annotation
    # if bookmarkToChange == None:
    #     print(f"There is no bookmark called '{bookmarkTitle}' in this pdf.")
    #     return

    try:
        # Selecting the first, top parent bookmark.
        bookmark = [annotation for _, annotation in metaObjects.items() if '/Title' in annotation][0]
    except IndexError:
        print("There are no bookmarks in this pdf.")
        return

    # Each bookmark is the child of the previous bookmark. They can be accessed from the parent with the '/Next' key.
    bookmarkAnnotations = [bookmark]
    while "/Next" in bookmark:
        if "/Title" not in bookmark["/Next"]:
            break
        bookmark = bookmark["/Next"]
        bookmarkAnnotations.append(bookmark)

    try:
        # Selecting the bookmark we want to add the url to.
        bookmarkToChange = [annotation for annotation in bookmarkAnnotations if annotation["/Title"] == f"({bookmarkTitle})".replace(" ", "\\040")][0]
    except IndexError:
        print(f"There is no bookmark called '{bookmarkTitle}' in this pdf.")
        return

    # Changing the internal PDF commands to point to a url instead of a page.
    bookmarkToChange.A.D = None                                                 # Deletes the page information the 'Go to page' action is pointing to.
    bookmarkToChange.A.S = pdfrw.PdfName("URI")                                 # Changes the 'Go to page' action to an 'Open a web link' action.
    bookmarkToChange.A.URI = pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString(f"({url})")      # Specifies the url for the 'Open a web link' action.

    # Saving the end result into a new file.
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(outputPdfPath, pdf)
```